# Delete list of entries by LINQ Query in ASP.Net MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, linq

I am a beginner in LINQ Queries. And In my ASP.Net MVC 5 project I need to delete a list of rows from DB. I am getting list of ID from UI which needs to be deleted. Below is what I am at till now.

```
private ApplicationDbContext _context;
public CityController()
{
    _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
}            

public ActionResult Delete(IEnumerable<int> listOfCityIdToDelete)
{
    _context.Cities
    .Where(c => listOfCityIdToDelete.Contains(c.Id))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(/*What do I put here?*/);
    return View();
}
```

I am not sure what to put in place for each line.

Comment: For an `IEnumerable` u can use `Except`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ForEach` is not a Linq command. Do something like this:

```
var cities = _context.Cities
    .Where(c => listOfCityIdToDelete.Contains(c.Id));
_context.Cities.RemoveRange(cities);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: So when we have one record we should use `Remove`. But if we are passing a list we should use `Remove Range`. eh?

Comment: Exactly. There is also an `AddRange` that does the same thing but for inserts

Comment: Till now for adding just one row I did something like `_context.cities.Add("the row");` and then call `_context.savechanges`